# Geodesic- the derivation of thei scalar product

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, inner-products, riemann-surfaces, geodesic

I would like to know how follows the $1$st $=$ in the very last formula in the snippet below
(i.e. one on the l.h.s. below) $$\frac{d}{dt}\langle\frac{dx}{dt},\frac{dx}{dt}\rangle=2\langle\frac{dx}{dt},\frac{\nabla}{dt}(\frac{dx}{dt})\rangle =0$$

[image]

Comment: The follows from the equation after "since $M$ is Riemannian" but now $t$ is the parameter for $x$ and replaces $\alpha$ and we substitute $dx/dt$ for both $v$ and $w$. In fancier language, the connection $\nabla$ is orthogonal.

Comment: @Max Thank you for your reply, but I definitely need a more detailed explanation. I do not know much about connections and $M$ being Riemannian and orthogonality of $\nabla$.

Comment: What do you understand $\nabla$ to mean?

Comment: @Max $\nabla f(x_1,...,x_n)$ is the vector of partial derivatives of $f$ along $x_i$,$i=1,...,n$ ? However I do not see how $\nabla$ is a connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like this boils down to understanding what is meant in your source by $\frac{\nabla}{\mathrm{d}t}$. In the comments you described the gradient, a sort of derivative of a function, but here $\frac{\nabla}{\mathrm{d}t}$ is a gadget for differentiating vector fields. For now, let's work in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $x=x(t)$ be a parameterized curve and let $v=(v^1,\dots,v^n)$ be a vector field. If we restrict $v$ to the curve $x(t)$, we can differentiate $v(x(t))$ with respect to $t$, obtaining a new vector field 
$$ \frac{\nabla}{\mathrm{d}t} v = \left( \frac{\mathrm{d} v^1}{\mathrm{d}t}, \dots , \frac{\mathrm{d} v^n}{\mathrm{d}t} \right) $$
defined along $x(t)$.

Now let $w=(w^1,\dots,w^n)$ be another vector field on $\mathbb{R}^n$. You can check that 
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \langle v,w \rangle_{x(t)} = \left\langle \frac{\nabla}{\mathrm{d}t} v, w \right\rangle + \left\langle  v, \frac{\nabla}{\mathrm{d}t} w \right\rangle .$$ 
This equation says that the covariant derivative along a curve preserves the inner product, and it's the reason we call $\nabla$ orthogonal. (You don't have to worry about what a connection is and what it means to say a connection is orthogonal at this point. Just note that $\nabla$ has this special property involving the metric.) All Riemannian manifolds have a unique torsion-free orthogonal affine connection, called the Levi-Civita connection; it's a gadget that let's us differentiate vector fields along curves.

I don't know what book you are using, but hopefully if you take a look at the section about covariant differentiation it should help. My suggestion would be to first make sure you understand the case for $\mathbb{R}^n$, then for submanifolds of $\mathbb{R}^n$, then for covariant differentiation on a Riemannian manifold intrinsically. The calculation you are asking about
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \left\langle \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t},\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} \right\rangle_{x(t)} = \left\langle \frac{\nabla}{\mathrm{d}t} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}, \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} \right\rangle + \left\langle  \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}, \frac{\nabla}{\mathrm{d}t} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} \right\rangle = 2 \left\langle \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t},\frac{\nabla}{\mathrm{d}t} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} \right\rangle$$ 
is just a special case of the property that $\nabla$ is orthogonal, plus the fact that the metric is symmetric. This equation implies that geodesics have constant speed.

Comment: You have answered what was unclear to me. I'm reading [this](http://93.174.95.29/main/533000/8e42fa2cbabe17c0e0068e5420d81ebb/Theodore%20Frankel%20-%20The%20Geometry%20of%20Physics_%20An%20Introduction%2C%20Second%20Edition%20%282003%29.pdf) book; could you suggest to me which chapter should I read for connections **and** covariant differentiations ?

Comment: Assuming you're comfortable with 8.1 and 8.6, you'll want to look at 9.1 and 9.2 at least.